# How to get the Activities url from the newest version of the Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, url, browser, ui-spy

In the newest version of the Chrome browser, uispy.exe can find the active tab URL. How is it done?

I know Visual Basic, c#, c++, delphi.

Comment: What is an activities URL?

Comment: @Explosion Pills    active tab URL

Comment: I haven't tried to inspect chrome with UISpy, but I guess it's a simple `GetWindowText` call.

Comment: @shaozeige Please provide what version of Chrome that is. Today's current version won't be the "newest version" tomorrow.

Comment: @ MPelletier chrome version 29